# List view with buttons at the bottom of dialog theme activity keep overlapping

Tags: android, listview, layout

I am working on android project where I have an activity which is using the theme holo dialog.

Within the dialog I have a list view and what I want to have is at the bottom always on show a linear layout which contains two buttons next to each other. The list view is populated by retrieving data from the call log and populating the adapter of the list.

The problem I am having is the list view always shows on top taking up the whole dialogue with the buttons at the bottom, with the content of the list overlapping the buttons. I want the list to be within the space of the top of the dialogue to the top of the linear layout button group. Below is the code for the main content view. This layout is set using the setContentView in the onCreate method

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/call_log_select_host_button_group"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <Button android:id="@+id/call_log_select_btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Block"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/call_log_select_btnBlock"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm not sure if it makes any difference but just in case the below is how I am populating the list and setting the view.

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            CallInformation callInformation = (CallInformation)arrayList.get(position);
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View rowView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.call_log_selection, parent, false);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.call_log_selector_image);

            if (callInformation.type == android.provider.CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE)
            {
                imageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.sym_call_incoming);
            }
            else if (callInformation.type == android.provider.CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE)
            {
                imageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.sym_call_outgoing);
            }
            else if (callInformation.type == android.provider.CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE)
            {
                imageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.sym_call_missed);
            }

            CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)rowView.findViewById(R.id.call_log_selector_checkbox);
            checkbox.setText(callInformation.content);
            checkbox.setTag(callInformation.telephone);
            return rowView;
        }
    }
```

The below code is the XML layout that is inflated by the adapter get view function

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/call_log_selector_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@android:drawable/stat_sys_phone_call"/>
        <CheckBox android:id="@+id/call_log_selector_checkbox"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try telling your `ListView` to stay above your `LinearLayout`

```
 <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/call_log_select_host_button_group>  // Add this line here
</ListView>
```

Comment: Please note that "fill_parent" is deprecated and "match_parent" should be used instead.

Comment: @Jschools thanks, that's actually one thing I always mention when I see it on a `layout` question but missed it this time. Good catch!

Comment: Yea I did have it as match parent but changed it to fill_parent just in case that was the reason. I've added the layout_above line but now the project doesn't compile as it says R.id.call_log_select_host_button_group is a duplicate field.

Comment: Either will work for now but `fill_parent` won't sometime in the future since it is deprecated. Do you have the "+" here `@+id`

Comment: Ah I did yea, it is working, a space got put on the end of the line somehow which caused the error, removed the space and the layout is working fine now. Thanks for the help